# Recursion with dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, pypdf, pypdf4

I am using *PyPDF4* to access to the "full" pdf-structures of a pdf and recursively store its values in a dictionary. The algorithm is supposed to work page-wise.

A pdf object for common data structure, `IndirectObject`, needs to be cast to dictionary via the `getObject()` method. Once the casting is performed then it is possible that some of its values are `IndirectObject` s themselves. They may occurs in lists and dictionaries and standalone:

- `{..., '/Kids': [IndirectObject(32, 0), ...], '/Count': 4}`
- `{'/ColorSpace': {'/CS0': IndirectObject(19023, 0), ...}`
- `{..., '/Parent': IndirectObject(26, 0), '/Resources': ...}`

The output of the program is incorrect, still some `IndirectObject` are presents. I tried several different implementations but I cannot see what I am doing wrong. How can I fix it?

For debugging purposes to each such substitution the key is modified to have the following pattern: `/OriginalKey_NumID`.

The output refers to a pdf that can be found [here](https://www.adobe.com/support/products/enterprise/knowledgecenter/media/c4611_sample_explain.pdf).

*PyPDF4* should be back-compatible with *PyPDF2*, just change the import part with *PyPDF2*. Now, *PyPDF2* seems to be in a reborn phase and some changes were made, see [history](https://pypdf2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/meta/history.html).

```
from PyPDF4 import PdfFileReader # should be also compatible with PyPDF2
from PyPDF4.pdf import IndirectObject


def inspect_page(c_dict):
    dg = {}
    def __inspect_page(c_dict):
        d = {}
        for k, v in c_dict.items():
            if isinstance(v, IndirectObject):
                #d[f'{k}_{v.idnum}'] = __inspect_page(v.getObject()) # lead to oo-recursion
                d[f'{k}_{v.idnum}'] = v.getObject()
            elif isinstance(v, list):
                loc_tmp = []
                for vv in v:
                    if isinstance(vv, IndirectObject):
                        local_d_tmp = {f'{k}_{vv.idnum}': __inspect_page(vv.getObject())}
                        loc_tmp.append(local_d_tmp)
                    elif isinstance(vv, dict):
                        loc_tmp.append(__inspect_page(vv))
                    else:
                        loc_tmp.append(vv)
                d[k] = loc_tmp
            elif isinstance(v, dict):
                v.update(__inspect_page(v))
                d[k] = v
            else:
                d[k] = v
        dg.update(d)
        return d

    __inspect_page(c_dict)
    return dg


#process pdf
# sample src: https://www.adobe.com/support/products/enterprise/knowledgecenter/media/c4611_sample_explain.pdf
path = # path to pdf
objects_pages = {}
rpdf = PdfFileReader(open(path, 'rb'))
for i in range(rpdf.getNumPages()):
    page = rpdf.getPage(i)
    objects_pages[i] = inspect_page(page)
    if i == 0:
        break

# check output
page_num = 0
print(f'content of page {page_num}')
for k, v in objects_pages[page_num].items():
    print(k, v)
```

Output (`IndirectObject` are still presents, both in list and as dictionary values)

```
content of page 0
/StructParents 0
/Rotate 0
/CS0_19023 ['/Separation', '/Black', '/DeviceCMYK', IndirectObject(19029, 0)]
/ColorSpace {'/CS0': IndirectObject(19023, 0), '/CS0_19023': ['/Separation', '/Black', '/DeviceCMYK', IndirectObject(19029, 0)]}
/T1_0_19022 {'/Subtype': '/Type1', '/FontDescriptor': IndirectObject(19024, 0), '/LastChar': 255, '/Widths': [...], '/BaseFont': '/Times-Roman', '/FirstChar': 0, '/Encoding': '/MacRomanEncoding', '/Type': '/Font'}
/T1_1_19027 {'/Subtype': '/Type1', '/FontDescriptor': IndirectObject(19028, 0), '/LastChar': 255, '/Widths': [...], '/BaseFont': '/Times-Italic', '/FirstChar': 0, '/Encoding': '/WinAnsiEncoding', '/Type': '/Font'}
/Font {'/T1_0': IndirectObject(19022, 0), '/T1_1': IndirectObject(19027, 0), '/T1_0_19022': {'/Subtype': '/Type1', '/FontDescriptor': IndirectObject(19024, 0), '/LastChar': 255, '/Widths': [...], '/BaseFont': '/Times-Roman', '/FirstChar': 0, '/Encoding': '/MacRomanEncoding', '/Type': '/Font'}, '/T1_1_19027': {'/Subtype': '/Type1', '/FontDescriptor': IndirectObject(19028, 0), '/LastChar': 255, '/Widths': [...], '/BaseFont': '/Times-Italic', '/FirstChar': 0, '/Encoding': '/WinAnsiEncoding', '/Type': '/Font'}}
/GS0_19025 {'/OPM': 1, '/op': <PyPDF4.generic.BooleanObject object at 0x7f0264627280>, '/Type': '/ExtGState', '/SA': <PyPDF4.generic.BooleanObject object at 0x7f0264627310>, '/SM': 0.02}
/ExtGState {'/GS0': IndirectObject(19025, 0), '/GS0_19025': {'/OPM': 1, '/op': <PyPDF4.generic.BooleanObject object at 0x7f0264627280>, '/Type': '/ExtGState', '/SA': <PyPDF4.generic.BooleanObject object at 0x7f0264627310>, '/SM': 0.02}}
/ProcSet ['/PDF', '/Text']
/Resources {'/ColorSpace': {'/CS0': IndirectObject(19023, 0), '/CS0_19023': ['/Separation', '/Black', '/DeviceCMYK', IndirectObject(19029, 0)]}, '/Font': {'/T1_0': IndirectObject(19022, 0), '/T1_1': IndirectObject(19027, 0), '/T1_0_19022': {'/Subtype': '/Type1', '/FontDescriptor': IndirectObject(19024, 0), '/LastChar': 255, '/Widths': [...], '/BaseFont': '/Times-Roman', '/FirstChar': 0, '/Encoding': '/MacRomanEncoding', '/Type': '/Font'}, '/T1_1_19027': {'/Subtype': '/Type1', '/FontDescriptor': IndirectObject(19028, 0), '/LastChar': 255, '/Widths': [...], '/BaseFont': '/Times-Italic', '/FirstChar': 0, '/Encoding': '/WinAnsiEncoding', '/Type': '/Font'}}, '/ProcSet': ['/PDF', '/Text'], '/ExtGState': {'/GS0': IndirectObject(19025, 0), '/GS0_19025': {'/OPM': 1, '/op': <PyPDF4.generic.BooleanObject object at 0x7f0264627280>, '/Type': '/ExtGState', '/SA': <PyPDF4.generic.BooleanObject object at 0x7f0264627310>, '/SM': 0.02}}}
/Type /Page
/CropBox [0, 0, 441, 666.36]
/Parent_18919 {'/Parent': IndirectObject(18918, 0), '/Count': 7, '/Type': '/Pages', '/Kids': [IndirectObject(19021, 0), IndirectObject(1, 0), IndirectObject(10, 0), IndirectObject(13, 0), IndirectObject(15, 0), IndirectObject(19, 0), IndirectObject(23, 0)]}
/Contents_19026 {'/Filter': '/FlateDecode'}
/BleedBox [0, 0, 441, 666.36]
/MediaBox [0, 0, 441, 666.36]
/Thumb_4489 {'/Filter': '/FlateDecode', '/BitsPerComponent': 8, '/ColorSpace': IndirectObject(2517, 0), '/Width': 55, '/Height': 83}
/TrimBox [0, 0, 441, 666.36]
```

---

EDIT:

`IndirectObject`s are uniquely identified by their `idnum` **but** a are not unique inside the PDF's structure. To avoid *oo*-recursion a set to keep track of each `idnum` should be created to avoid duplicates.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: PyPDF2 and PyPDF4 have a common ancestor, but they diverged. I'm certainly biased, but I'd strongly recommend to go with PyPDF2.

Comment: goal: make the recursion work, get a dictionary which values do not contained `IndirectObject`